# Proving a function f that for every sequence $x1,x2,x3, \ldots$

Tags: real-analysis

Proving a function $f$ that for every sequence in $x1,x2,x3,\ldots$ in the domain of $f$ converging to a point $x$ we have that $f(x_1)$,$f(x_2)$,$f(x_3)$, ... converges to $f(x)$ then $f$ is continuous at $x$.

I have begun proving this by contradiction.

Proof: Let $f$ be a function defined at $x$.
Suppose that every sequence $p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots$ on the domain of $f$ converging to $x$ has the property that $f(p_1),f(p_2),f(p_3),\ldots$ converges to $f(x)$.
$f$ is continuous at $x$ means that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$,
such that for all $t$ in the domain with $|t-x| < \delta$,
but $|f(t)-f(x)| \geq 0$. (assuming that $f$ is NOT continuous)

there is where I am stuck.

How would I go about constructing a sequence of points in the domain of $f$ that converges to $x$ but the sequence of images of that sequence under $f$ does not converge to $f(x)$?

Comment: $f$ is a real valued function whose domain is a subset of $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2):

Your contra-positive statement is not correct. It should be, there exists some $\epsilon_{0}>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$, there exists some $x_{\delta}$ with $|x_{\delta}-x|<\delta$ and $|f(x_{\delta})-f(x)|\geq\epsilon_{0}$.

Realizing $\delta>0$ to each $1/n$, one get a sequence $(x_{n})$ with $|x_{n}-x|<1/n$ and $|f(x_{n})-f(x)|\geq\epsilon_{0}$, the formal inequality indicates that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ so by assumption it is then $f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x)$. Taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ to the latter inequality and use Squeeze Theorem to get $0\geq\epsilon_{0}$.

Comment: What do you mean by xn→x ?

Comment: $x_{n}$ converges to $x$.